# Using i18next for a react production build causes the translation to display only strings

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, localhost, i18next

I believe I have searched all parts of the internet for an answer and fixes but none seem to work.

Issue :

- When building a react app for production that uses i18n as a translation will cause the production build to only display the strings only as a result and not the translated text itself (see picture reference)[image: Example of result in the production build]
- The weird part is that inside localhost when the development server is running it display the translation correctly. (see picture for reference)[image: Wanted result for the production build]
- After building the production build, inside the browser console (using chrome) it displays the following error : `Fetch API cannot load file:///Documents/streaming_site/build/static/locales/en/translation.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`

After seeing this error, I imediately came to the assumption that it was inside my `i18next.js` file that was causing the issue. Here is the file :

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';

// don't want to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide 
// for passing in lng and translations on init

const Languages = ['en', 'fr'];

i18n
  .use(XHR)
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    lng : 'en',
    react: { 
      useSuspense: false,
      wait: true
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: false,
    whitelist: Languages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    nsSeperator : false,
    keySeperator : false,
    backend:{
      loadPath: () => {

        var cors = require('cors');
        var app = cors();
        
        // check the domain
        const host = window.location.host;
        return (host === 'index.html#' ? '':'') + '/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json';
      },
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

Furhtermore inside my `index.js` file I added these extra fixes to ensure that the app would properly display the translated text on a production build :

```
i18next.init({// <-- This was added
  interpolation: {escapeValue: false},
});
i18next.init().then(() => // <-- This was added
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>// <-- This was added
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>// <-- This was added
        <App />
      </I18nextProvider>
    </Suspense>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
);
```

Alas, the same error occurs (the one from the third point) after making an `npm run build`

This leads me to believe that it is impossible without a backend server hosting the `translation.json` files for en and fr to have them be accessed locally.

My questions is the following: Is it possible to have i18n translation run locally after building the production build without needing a server to host the json files? If yes how would I proceed?

For references I have tried a few fixes from this website such as :

1. [React i18next Backend-Path different in local and production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774175/react-i18next-backend-path-different-in-local-and-production-environment)
2. [react-i18next doesn't translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61753612/react-i18next-doesnt-translate)
3. [Allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin header using HTML5 fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878255/allow-access-control-allow-origin-header-using-html5-fetch-api)

I've gotten close when I attempted --> `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");` although it comes at the cost of posing some security issue and I don't want that. Although if this is a potential fix, I am willing to try it.

So here I am out of ideas... :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some misconfig of the i18next service.

First of all, `i18next-http-backend` & `i18next-xhr-backend` are solving the same problem, fetching json files.

Remove the second one (`i18next-xhr-backend`) since it is deprecated in favor of `i18next-http-backend`.

Change the `backend.loadPath` to be a string, your code doesn't make sense.

it should look like:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

// don't want to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide
// for passing in lng and translations on init

const Languages = ['en', 'fr'];

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
      wait: true,
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: false,
    whitelist: Languages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    nsSeperator: false,
    keySeperator: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fix, but when I attempted to create a new prod build the debug console in Chrome displays the same issue : 

`Fetch API cannot load file:///Users/user/Documents/streaming_site/build/static/locales/en/translation.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`

https://imgur.com/a/D3CFiBZ

So the app finds the json with no problem but chrome refuses to load it due to this error. I also tried other browsers such as Safari and the same issue occurs.

Comment: How do you lunch the app?

Comment: I just drag & drop the index.html into Chrome or do `open with > Chrome`

Comment: So this is your issue, since you are opening the index.html file as `file://` protocol. This is not allows you to make Ajax requests. You need to serve the html file using some server, (like webpack-dev-server serves your file at dev time)