# React i18next doesn't display translation after running npm build

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django, i18next

React i18next fails to fetch translation from the JSON file after running the build command. Note, everything works fine without the build in react localhost:3000

I'm using React build file in Django.

I checked a similar issue but the solution didn't work for me : [Using i18next for a react production build causes the translation to display only strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431391/using-i18next-for-a-react-production-build-causes-the-translation-to-display-onl)

index.js :

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import './index.css';

const languages = [
  {
    code: 'fr',
    name: 'Français',
    country_code: 'fr'
  },
  {
    code: 'en',
    name : 'English',
    country_code: 'en'
  },
  {
    code: 'ar',
    name: 'العربية',
    country_code: 'ly',
    dir: 'rtl'
  }
]

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
      wait: true,
    },
    // the translations
    // (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
    // or even better, manage them via a UI: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files#manage-your-translations-with-a-management-gui)
    supported: ["en", "fr", "ar"],
    fallbackLng: "en",
    detection: {
      order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie'],
    },
    debug: false,
    whitelist: languages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    nsSeperator: false,
    keySeperator: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
    },
  });

  const loadingMarkup = (
    <div className='index__loading'>
      <h2>Loading..</h2>
    </div>
  )

ReactDOM.render(
  <Suspense fallback={loadingMarkup}>
    <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  </Suspense>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

loginheader where i click to switch between languages :

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './LoginHeader.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';
import SortIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Sort';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import Alert from './Alert';
// import Drower from './Drower';
import Logo from '../assets/images/logo.png';
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { FormControl, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
// import LanguageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Language';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import cookies from 'js-cookie';

const languages = [
  {
    code: 'fr',
    name: 'Français',
    country_code: 'fr'
  },
  {
    code: 'en',
    name : 'English',
    country_code: 'en'
  },
  {
    code: 'ar',
    name: 'العربية',
    country_code: 'ly',
    dir: 'rtl'
  }
]

function LoginHeader({ logout, isAuthenticated }) {

  const currentLanguageCode = cookies.get('i18next') || 'en';
  const currentLanguage = languages.find(l => l.code === currentLanguageCode);
  useEffect (() => {
    document.body.dir = currentLanguage.dir || 'ltr'
    // document.title = t('app_title')
  },[currentLanguage]);

  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const [value, setValue] = useState('English')
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }
  
  const guestLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='loginHeader__right'>
        <div className='middle__header__bx'>
    
          <div className='loginHeader__main__btns'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__loginButton' to='/login'><button>{t('header_login')}</button></Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__signupButton' to='/signup'><button>{t('header_signup')}</button></Link>
          </div> 
        
          <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown'>
          <button className='dropdown__btn dropdown__services'>{t('header_services')}<ExpandMoreIcon className='services__expand'/></button>
          <div className='dropdown__content dropdown__services__content'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('services_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('services_addmissionOffers')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/application-form'>{t('services_forms')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('services_premium')}</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* start of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__lang'>
          <div className='loginHeader__lang__bx'>
            <div className='loginHeader__lang__container'>
              <Select
                className='loginHeader__select'
                labelId='select-demo'
                id='language-select'
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                disableUnderline
                variant='standard'
              >
                {languages.map(({code, name, country_code}) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    value={name} 
                    key={country_code}
                  >
                    <button 
                      onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage(code)}
                      className='loginHeader__lang__btn'
                    >
                      {name}
                    </button>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
              </Select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown sortIcon__bx'>
          <SortIcon className='dropdown__btn loginHeader__sortIcon'/>
          <div className='dropdown__content sortIcon__dropdown'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('header_dropdown_prem')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('header_dropdown_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('header_dropdown_admission')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/request-service'>{t('header_dropdown_requestService')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/contact'>{t('header_dropdown_contact')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/signup'>{t('header_signup')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/login'>{t('header_login')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/guid'>{t('header_dropdown_guide')}</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        
       </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );

  const authLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='loginHeader__right'>
      {/* <button onClick={logout} className='loginHeader__logout__btn'>{t('header_logout')}</button> */}
        {/* start of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__logged__lang'>
          <div className='loginHeader__lang__bx'>
            <FormControl>
              <Select
                className='loginHeader__select'
                labelId='select-demo'
                id='language-select'
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                disableUnderline
                variant='standard'
              >
                {languages.map(({code, name, country_code}) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    value={name} 
                    key={country_code}
                  >
                    <button 
                      onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage(code)}
                      className='loginHeader__lang__btn'
                      disabled={code === currentLanguageCode}
                    >
                      {name}
                    </button>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end of lang box */}
      <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown loggedin__icon__bx'>
          <button className='dropdown__btn'><SortIcon className='loginHeader__sortIcon logedin__sortIcon'/></button>
          <div className='dropdown__content logged__sortIcon__dropdown'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('header_dropdown_prem')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('header_dropdown_admission')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('header_dropdown_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/request-service'>{t('header_dropdown_requestService')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/contact'>{t('header_dropdown_contact')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/guid'>{t('header_dropdown_guide')}</Link>
            <button onClick={logout} className='logout__btn'>{t('header_logout')}</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <div className='loginHeader'>
      <div className='loginHeader__left'>
        <Link to='/'><img className='logo' src={Logo} alt='logo'/></Link>  
      </div>
      {isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks()}
      <Alert/>
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout }) (LoginHeader);
```

Also, other way but same results, I seperated files and created i18n.js file to make it as follows :
i18n.js :

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

// don't want to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide
// for passing in lng and translations on init

const languages = [
    {
      code: 'fr',
      name: 'Français',
      country_code: 'fr'
    },
    {
      code: 'en',
      name : 'English',
      country_code: 'en'
    },
    {
      code: 'ar',
      name: 'العربية',
      country_code: 'ly',
      dir: 'rtl'
    }
  ]

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
      wait: true,
    },
    // the translations
    // (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
    // or even better, manage them via a UI: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files#manage-your-translations-with-a-management-gui)
    supported: ["en", "fr", "ar"],
    fallbackLng: "en",
    detection: {
      order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie'],
    },
    debug: false,
    whitelist: languages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    nsSeperator: false,
    keySeperator: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

index.js :

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import i18n from "i18next";
import i18next from "i18next";
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import './i18n';

  i18next.init({// <-- This was added
    interpolation: {escapeValue: false},
  });

i18next.init().then(() => // <-- This was added
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Suspense fallback={<div className='index__loading'><h2>Loading...</h2></div>}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <App />
        </I18nextProvider>
      </Suspense>,
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
);
```

loginheader.js :

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './LoginHeader.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';
import SortIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Sort';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import Alert from './Alert';
// import Drower from './Drower';
import Logo from '../assets/images/logo.png';
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { FormControl, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
// import LanguageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Language';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import cookies from 'js-cookie';

const languages = [
  {
    code: 'fr',
    name: 'Français',
    country_code: 'fr'
  },
  {
    code: 'en',
    name : 'English',
    country_code: 'en'
  },
  {
    code: 'ar',
    name: 'العربية',
    country_code: 'ly',
    dir: 'rtl'
  }
]

function LoginHeader({ logout, isAuthenticated }) {

  const currentLanguageCode = cookies.get('i18next') || 'en';
  const currentLanguage = languages.find(l => l.code === currentLanguageCode);
  useEffect (() => {
    document.body.dir = currentLanguage.dir || 'ltr'
    // document.title = t('app_title')
  },[currentLanguage]);

  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const [value, setValue] = useState('English')
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }
  
  const guestLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='loginHeader__right'>
        <div className='middle__header__bx'>
    
          <div className='loginHeader__main__btns'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__loginButton' to='/login'><button>{t('header_login')}</button></Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__signupButton' to='/signup'><button>{t('header_signup')}</button></Link>
          </div> 
        
          <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown'>
          <button className='dropdown__btn dropdown__services'>{t('header_services')}<ExpandMoreIcon className='services__expand'/></button>
          <div className='dropdown__content dropdown__services__content'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('services_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('services_addmissionOffers')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/application-form'>{t('services_forms')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('services_premium')}</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* start of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__lang'>
          <div className='loginHeader__lang__bx'>
            <div className='loginHeader__lang__container'>
              <Select
                className='loginHeader__select'
                labelId='select-demo'
                id='language-select'
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                disableUnderline
                variant='standard'
              >
                {languages.map(({code, name, country_code}) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    value={name} 
                    key={country_code}
                  >
                    <button 
                      onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage(code)}
                      className='loginHeader__lang__btn'
                    >
                      {name}
                    </button>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
              </Select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown sortIcon__bx'>
          <SortIcon className='dropdown__btn loginHeader__sortIcon'/>
          <div className='dropdown__content sortIcon__dropdown'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('header_dropdown_prem')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('header_dropdown_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('header_dropdown_admission')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/request-service'>{t('header_dropdown_requestService')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/contact'>{t('header_dropdown_contact')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/signup'>{t('header_signup')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/login'>{t('header_login')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/guid'>{t('header_dropdown_guide')}</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        
       </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );

  const authLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='loginHeader__right'>
      {/* <button onClick={logout} className='loginHeader__logout__btn'>{t('header_logout')}</button> */}
        {/* start of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__logged__lang'>
          <div className='loginHeader__lang__bx'>
            <FormControl>
              <Select
                className='loginHeader__select'
                labelId='select-demo'
                id='language-select'
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                disableUnderline
                variant='standard'
              >
                {languages.map(({code, name, country_code}) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    value={name} 
                    key={country_code}
                  >
                    <button 
                      onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage(code)}
                      className='loginHeader__lang__btn'
                      disabled={code === currentLanguageCode}
                    >
                      {name}
                    </button>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end of lang box */}
      <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown loggedin__icon__bx'>
          <button className='dropdown__btn'><SortIcon className='loginHeader__sortIcon logedin__sortIcon'/></button>
          <div className='dropdown__content logged__sortIcon__dropdown'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('header_dropdown_prem')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('header_dropdown_admission')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('header_dropdown_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/request-service'>{t('header_dropdown_requestService')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/contact'>{t('header_dropdown_contact')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/guid'>{t('header_dropdown_guide')}</Link>
            <button onClick={logout} className='logout__btn'>{t('header_logout')}</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <div className='loginHeader'>
      <div className='loginHeader__left'>
        <Link to='/'><img className='logo' src={Logo} alt='logo'/></Link>  
      </div>
      {isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks()}
      <Alert/>
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout }) (LoginHeader);
```

Comment: call init just once… set debug to true and check the development console output… compare with https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip but now i'm getting : i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed failed parsing /locales/en/translation.json to json

Comment: so seems your translation.json file is not a valid json (it might be there is some leading comma or similar)